# Laravel : retrieve other relationship from relationship called

Tags: laravel, database, relationship, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

So, i have this collection that i've been convert toArray , this is my collection :

```
 array:1 [▼
  0 => array:14 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "timeout" => "2022-05-29 15:15:34"
    "address" => "Awikwok"
    "regency" => "["Kotawaringin Barat"]"
    "province" => "["Jawa Tengah"]"
    "total" => 68000
    "shipping_cost" => 18000
    "sub_total" => 50000
    "user_id" => 1
    "proof_of_payment" => null
    "status" => "PENDING"
    "created_at" => "2022-05-28T15:15:34.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2022-05-28T15:15:34.000000Z"
    "user" => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "user"
      "email" => "user@gmail.com"
      "email_verified_at" => null
      "created_at" => "2022-05-28T15:12:21.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2022-05-28T15:12:21.000000Z"
      "carts" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:7 [▼
          "id" => 1
          "user_id" => 1
          "product_id" => 2
          "qty" => 1
          "created_at" => "2022-05-28T15:12:39.000000Z"
          "updated_at" => "2022-05-28T15:12:39.000000Z"
          "products" => array:10 [▼
            "id" => 2
            "product_name" => "Hitam baju"
            "price" => 50000
            "description" => "kjeqwoejwqpoewq"
            "product_rate" => "0"
            "stock" => "5"
            "weight" => "4"
            "deleted_at" => null
            "created_at" => "2022-05-28T15:11:54.000000Z"
            "updated_at" => "2022-05-28T15:11:54.000000Z"
          ]
        ]
        1 => array:7 [▶]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

in this case, i want to show product attribute from transaction table , but here's my code :

```
 @foreach ($transactionByUser->user->carts as $item)
                        <div class="col-lg-3 m-0">

                            <h6> <b>Product name </b> <br> </h6>
                            <h6> <b>Price </b> <br> </h6>
                            <h6> <b>Qty </b> <br> </h6>
                            <h6> <b>Shipping Cost </b> <br> </h6>
                            <h6> <b>Sub total </b></h6>
                            <h6> <b> &nbsp; </b></h6>
                            <br>
                            <h6> <b> Total </b></h6>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 text-end m-0">
                            <h6>{{ $item->products['product_name'] }}</h6>
                            <h6>Rp.{{ number_format($item->products->price) }}</h6>
                            <h6>{{ $item->qty }} item</h6>
                            <h6>Rp. {{ number_format($transactionByUser->shipping_cost) }}</h6>
                            <h6>{{ $item->qty }} item * Rp.{{ number_format($item->products->price) }} = </h6>
                            <h6>Rp.{{ number_format($transactionByUser->sub_total) }}</h6>
                            <hr>
                            <h6>Rp.{{ number_format($transactionByUser->total) }}</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            @foreach ($item->products->images as $image)
                                <img class="img-thumbnail h-75" src="{{ asset('images/' . $image->image_name) }}" alt="">
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    @endforeach
```

the problem is, when i do render like that, it's retrieving all product instead current product that i want to show it, how to fix it?

Comment: Could you show, how you are retriving `transactionByUser` on contoller.

Comment: $transactionByUser = Transaction::with(['user.carts.products'])->get()->toArray();

Comment: You want to show all the products from current transaction only or??

Comment: no, it's only products that i want to show the detail. i mean it's upload payment proof view, so when i access the view, it's only showing the specific product based on Transaction::find($id).